# finding index of the last node of a treeview C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

I am trying to copy a `treeview` to a new one except the last node and all its children. Then I wrote a `for` loop to do so. But I want to limit `for` loop from above till the last node. Then I need to know the last node's index. 
How can I find it?

Comment: Please provide your code

Comment: You could simply stop you for-loop one index before the last - `for(int i = 0; i < (nodes.Length - 1); i++)`

Comment: Simply use `TreeView.GetNodeCount(false)`. It returns the number of nodes, which you can use in your for-loop.

Answer (score 1):

As  Lars Kristensen mentioned:

```
for(int i = 0; i < (nodes.Length - 1); i++)
```